# How change path in Node for modules?

Tags: node.js

i have node js project.

```
/home/sergey/Desktop/core/app.mjs
```

In app.mjs i am import file

```
import test from '/static/test.mjs'
```

But when i run node `node app.mjs` import not found because code search file in `/static`

how to tell node to search all paths starting from `/home/sergey/Desktop/core` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should import a relative path, instead of an absolute one:

`import test from './static/test.mjs'`

Comment: I cannot use this option

Comment: this is the path I use in the repositories to access the web.  there the main route cannot be used.  on the client there is only a path from the project root.

Comment: This is good, but I use galp for transforming paths.